# Prove that $\{c_1,…,c_n\}$ is independent if and only if $\text{null}(A)=\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove that $\{c_1,…,c_n\}$ is independent if and only if $\text{null}(A)=\{0\}$

I understand that for the columns of the matrix $A$ to be independent, the linear combination has to be trivial, and we know that $Ax = 0$.

I am not sure how to go about synthesizing the proof.

Edit: Matrix $A is not a square matrix

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you prove null $A$={0} $\iff$ {$c_1,...,c_n$} is independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550284/how-do-you-prove-null-a-0-iff-c-1-c-n-is-independent)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $A$ has columns $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n$, then

$$Ax = 0 \Leftrightarrow x_1c_1 + x_2c_2 + \ldots x_nc_n = 0$$

See for example [matrix multiplication using columns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64631/matrix-multiplication-by-columns/4298400#4298400), which is a neat way of writing down a matrix multiplication.

Now $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ are linearly independent if and only if the $x_i = 0$ for all $i$. Hence the nullspace of $A$ equals $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have: $\text{null}(A) = 0\iff A \text{ is invertible} \iff \text{det}(A) \neq 0\iff \text{ the columns of A are linearly independent}$.

Comment: No, this assumes $A$ is a square matrix.